# How do I get gsub on my centos box?

Tags: centos

I have a centos box and when I try gsub, it doesn't work:

```
-bash: gsub: command not found
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get gsub on my box. Trying to get a script working that checks download speeds on a server. Here is the line:

```
cachefly=$( wget -O /dev/null http://cachefly.cachefly.net/100mb.test 2>&1 | awk '/\/dev\/null/ {speed=$3 $4} END {gsub(/\(|\)/,"",speed); print speed}' )
```

The line isn't outputting correctly, I think because gsub isn't found? It's suppose to print the speed it downloaded the file, the only output I get is "MB/s-"

Comment: Which `gsub` are you trying to use? `awk`? ruby? R?

Comment: It's a part of a bash script. The script also uses the awk command, that works fine on my box

Comment: Could edit your question to included the problematic `awk` incantation? Include any relative script blocks if quoting or scoping may apply.

Comment: On CentOS, `awk` is GNU `awk`.  Guessing your box (where the command works) is not CentOS? Maybe Ubuntu?  On Debian, `awk` is symlinked to `mawk`.  There are minor differences in their syntax.  Can you verify the distros and versions of "`awk`" your using?

Comment: Linux version 2.6.18-028stab091.2 (root@rhel5-build-x64) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46) ..... cat /etc/*release* = 
CentOS release 5.3 (Final) ...... awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.5